# Handling onActivityResult from outside the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm trying to make a helper class to start an `Activity` and get the return result (`startActivityForResult`) to avoid developers writing their own `onActivityResult` code and encapsulate the complex internal details.

ie: the caller's code:

```
MyIntent i = new MyIntent();
i.getMyData(new OnData() { public void onData(Bundle data) {....} );
```

I tried creating a "dummy" `Activity` inside MyIntent just to be able to override `onActivityResult`, but the activity needs to be declared in the manifest, which is what the helper class tries to avoid. There is no "setOnActivityResult" which would be a good alternative.

So, how to create an `Activity` programmatically and "attach" it so it has valid state?

After creating `new Activity()` I'd like to call the Activity "attach" which is internal.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> So, how to create an Activity programmatically and "attach" it so it has valid state?

That is not possible, sorry.

> I'm trying to make a helper class to start an Activity and get the return result (startActivityForResult) to avoid developers writing their own onActivityResult code and encapsulate the complex internal details.

That is not possible, sorry. The closest you can get is how the Barcode Scanner integration JAR works -- you delegate `onActivityResult()` to them to decode the result obtained from the scanner activity.

Comment: I am also trying for the same thing just check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener.html I am using this to call the  onActivityResult() method in custom class but it is not working... if u have any idea ... then plz post .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could a simple callback be an alternative? User places callback in static field of your library and your library will invoke this callback when required. The most straightforward implementation could be:

```
YourSdk.staticCallbackField=new OnData() { public void onData(Bundle data) {....});
MyIntent i = new MyIntent();
startActivity(i);
```

When you SDK completes it's job it invokes callback:

```
staticCallbackField.onData(data)
```

User activity will get *Bundle data* in callback instead of onActivityResult.

You should be aware of possible activity lifecycle issues. For example if android recreates user activity in the background callback should be recreated.